# Dynamically implement __str__ if not implemented

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass

I am trying to write a function, strFix, that takes a class object as parameter, and checks if the class has an **str**() method , and if not will automatically add one, that prints all the member variables on one line eg: prints number of sides, list of sides and area of the triangle.

However, after calling `strFix(triangle)` i get a triangle object returned instead of printing it?

```py
def constructor(self, arg):
    self.no_of_sides = arg


def setSidesT(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    self.listattr = [x, y, z]


def createSubClass(self):

    self = type(
        "Triangle",  # subclass name
        (Polygon,),  # super class(es)
        {
            "listattr": [],  # new attributes and functions/methods
            "setSides": setSidesT,
            "findArea": (lambda obj: (obj.x + obj.y + obj.z) / 2),
            "getTriangleSides": (lambda x: print(x.listattr)),
        },
    )
    return self


Polygon = type(
    "Polygon",
    (object,),
    {
        "no_of_sides": 0,
        "__init__": constructor,
        "getSides": (lambda obj: obj.no_of_sides),
    },
)


def Tprinter(self):
    return str(self.no_of_sides, self.getTriangleSides, self.findArea)


def strFix(self):
    if not type(self).__dict__.get("__str__"):
        setattr(self, "__str__", Tprinter)


triangle = createSubClass(Polygon)(3)
triangle.setSides(4, 5, 6)
triangle.getTriangleSides()
strFix(triangle)
print(triangle.findArea())
print(triangle)
```

Comment: Why though? It would be clearer to use a base class or a mixin class.

Comment: Unless you are passing an anonymous type as a function argument, use a `class` statement instead of calling `type`. This is analogous to preferring `def` over a lambda expression for defining named functions.

Comment: @AKX I understand but its a requirement to implement the classes as metaclasses and also implement the strfix function as so

Comment: You have no metaclasses in this code. A metaclass would be a *subclass* of `type`, not an instance of `type`.

Comment: The `__str__` method needs to go in the class, *not* an instance of the class.

Comment: @Misu "It's a requirement" – is this school work of some sort..?

Comment: @AKX yes i am just stuck here though

Comment: @jasonharper how can i do so?

Comment: If you really have to add the method later on, instead of just inheriting from a base class - `.__class__` on an object gives you the corresponding class, which you can then manipulate with the same sort of `setattr` and `__dict__` logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use a classbody, and a regular superclass with a default  `__str__` -  it is at the sametime the normal thing to do, and does what you want.

That said, your `strFix` function plugs an `__str__` method on the *instance*, and that won't work - you have to set `__str__` on the class itself.

And also, no need to use  `setattr`  when `=` suffices:

```py
def strFix(instance):
    cls = instance.__class__
    if "__str__" not in cls.__dict__:
        cls.__str__ = Tprinter
```

Comment: Here we are modifying the __str__ method of an instance but not an object right?

Comment: "an instance" and "an object" mean exactly the samthing. The code snippet modifies the method in the *class* (which is the samething as the instance's *type*). Python looks at the class of an object to check for the magic methods like `__str__`